# Crontab fails at switching backgrounds linux mint

Tags: linux-mint, x11, cron, gsettings

I wrote the following crontab task which should switch my backgound image every 10 minutes on linux mint:

```
*/10 * * * * /home/me/Pictures/wallpapers/switcher.sh >> /home/me/Logs/wallpaper.log 2>&1
```

Which calls this shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
gsettings set org.cinnamon.desktop.background picture-uri $(/usr/bin/python3 /home/me/Pictures/wallpapers/spaceBack.py)
```

In the log file I get this error message:

```
(process:18951): dconf-CRITICAL **: 14:00:02.264: unable to create file '/home/me/.cache/dconf/user': Permission denied.  dconf will not work properly.
(process:18951): dconf-CRITICAL **: 14:00:02.265: unable to create file '/home/me/.cache/dconf/user': Permission denied.  dconf will not work properly.
(process:18951): dconf-CRITICAL **: 14:00:02.265: unable to create file '/home/me/.cache/dconf/user': Permission denied.  dconf will not work properly.
(process:18951): dconf-WARNING **: 14:00:02.265: failed to commit changes to dconf: Cannot autolaunch D-Bus without X11 $DISPLAY
```

I only get this error when running the shell script via `cron` (it works fine via terminal).

calling `ls -la /home/me/.cache/dconf/` 
Returns

```
drwx------  2 root  root  4096 Jul  6 16:13 .
drwx------ 48 me me 4096 Jun 29 15:33 ..
-rw-------  1 root  root     2 Jul  6 16:13 user
```

Comment: Try `echo $DISPLAY` and place the resulting value in your cron command like so:
`DISPLAY=<value returned from echo> /home/me/Pictures/wallpapers/switcher.sh [...]`

Comment: it slightly changed the error message to 
```...
(process:21877): dconf-WARNING **: 16:04:05.657: failed to commit changes to dconf: Could not connect: Connection refused```
the DISPLAY value is ```:0```

Comment: What user is this `crontab` running as?

Comment: Seems to be running as ```me```

Comment: That's most likely the issue - you should use your regular user.

Comment: I tried with both (sudo crontab and just crontab, and neither works)

Comment: Add the output of `ls -la /home/me/.cache/dconf/` to your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` has to be set as an environment variable. Its proper value can be set via the following script, taken from this question asking [How to change Gsettings via remote shell?](https://askubuntu.com/a/457023)

```
#!/bin/bash

# Remember to run this script using the command "source ./filename.sh"

# Search these processes for the session variable 
# (they are run as the current user and have the DBUS session variable set)
compatiblePrograms=( nautilus kdeinit kded4 pulseaudio trackerd )

# Attempt to get a program pid
for index in ${compatiblePrograms[@]}; do
    PID=$(pidof -s ${index})
    if [[ "${PID}" != "" ]]; then
        break
    fi
done
if [[ "${PID}" == "" ]]; then
    echo "Could not detect active login session"
    return 1
fi

QUERY_ENVIRON="$(tr '\0' '\n' < /proc/${PID}/environ | grep "DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS" | cut -d "=" -f 2-)"
if [[ "${QUERY_ENVIRON}" != "" ]]; then
    export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS="${QUERY_ENVIRON}"
    echo "Connected to session:"
    echo "DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=${DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS}"
else
    echo "Could not find dbus session ID in user environment."
    return 1
fi

return 0
```

The cron job can then be modified to this: `*/10 * * * * DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus /home/me/Pictures/wallpapers/switcher.sh >> /home/me/Logs/wallpaper.log 2>&1`